# Is there an option flag to ignore any javascript errors in uglifyjs?

Tags: node.js, uglifyjs

I'm using uglifyjs module in node.js. When I use the following command to minify my scripts, I get a javascript parse error from uglifyjs. Is there a way to ignore it?

I like to check my js errors in browser, not with uglifyjs.

**cat file1.js file2.js | uglifyjs -o minified.js**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uglification/minification tools need to completely rewrite your javascript. It won't be always possible rewrite it in a way that will preserve your error intact, and it is certainly not something that authors of such tools would waste time to implement.